# Iterator throwing illegalstateexception after calling .next()

Tags: java, while-loop, iterator, illegalstateexception

```
//This method compares two ArrayLists of strings and compares whether the words in one array list contain the letters in the other.

    public static void remove()
    {
        //Create iterators for both stringList and letterList
        Iterator<String> iterWords = stringList.iterator();
        Iterator<String> iterLetters = letterList.iterator();

        //First while loop will go over all strings in stringList via the iterWords iterator
        while(iterWords.hasNext())
        {
            //iterWords now has a .next() call

            String word = iterWords.next();
            //Second while loop that should run over each letter in letterList and compare it to each word in stringList
            while(iterLetters.hasNext())
            {
                //iterLetter now has a .next() call
                String letter = iterLetters.next();
                //if statement to remove the entry in stringList if it does not contain the current letter.  It is this part that throws the illegalstateexception
                if(word.contains(letter) == false)
                {
                    //This is the line that is causing the illegalstateexceptions
                    iterWords.remove();
                }           
            }
        }
    }
```

Hello everyone, I am looking for some insight concerning an exception I am getting while iterating over two arraylists.  I have simplified the above arraylists and removed any methods that are not relevant to the problem.
I am getting an illegalstateexception on the last iterWords.remove().  In the outside while loop I have done iterWords.next(), so iterWords.remove() should be seeing something to remove.
I am guessing that this is throwing the exception because of the fact that I am calling iterWords.remove() from the inner while loop.  Do you think this might be the case?
Thank you for any insight that you can bring.

Comment: Um... a method that _"compares"_ things shouldn't be called `remove`.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right.  I named it that just for the posting so readers would know that this was the method where the problems with .remove() were taking place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should read, and post, the exception.

Second: you're calling `remove()` several times, after calling `next()` just once: as many times as there are letters that are not contained in the word.

Third: since you're always using the same letter iterator, once you've done the first word, you don't iterate on the letters anymore.

So you must:

- stop iterating on letters as soon as you've removed the word
- recreate the letter iterator at each iteration of the outer loop. Or better, just use a foreach loop: you don't need an iterator for the inner loop.
  Your code would be much simpler, readable and safer if you used methods:

  ```
  for (Iterator<String> it: words; it.hasNext(); ) {
      String word : it.next();
      if (anyLetterNotInWord(letters, word) {
          it.remove();
      }
  }
  ```

If you're on Java 8, this can be reduced to

```
words.removeIf(word -> anyLetterNotInWord(letters, word));
```

where `anyLetterNotInWord()` can be defined as

```
return letters.stream().anyMatch(letter -> !word.contains(letter));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Yes, that was definitely the problem.  It works like a charm now.  Very interesting information about Java 8.  That seems like a much easier thing to use as compared to my confusing method :).  Again, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. In case you don't know, the way to say thank you hereis by upvoting and/or accepting the answer. That also signals to others that your problem has been solved.